# Monitor URL to indicate that a service is up

Tags: nagios, health-monitoring

How can I monitor an URL, for example: https://www.example.com/status and look for the number '1' as an indicator that the service is up?

Answer (score 2):

check_mk_active-http -H www.example.com -u '/status?depth=0' -s "1"

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with [check_http](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http), which is a standard plugin.

Look at the -u and -s options, although there's no reason to limit your status codes to "0" or "1".

So, something like this:

```
/path/to/check_http --ssl -H www.example.com -u /status -s "1"
```